# Given sufficient memory, are locks unnecessary when there is only a single dedicated writer thread?

Tags: multithreading, locking, mutex, atomic, lockless

For a scenario with multiple reader threads and a single writer thread, where the readers are allowed to read slightly outdated data, I've concocted a lockless control flow as shown below in its most basic form in pseudocode:

```
GLOBAL_ATOMIC_POINTER shared_pointer

// Only called by the reader threads.
read()
    THREAD_LOCAL_POINTER read_pointer := shared_pointer
    return read_data_at(read_pointer)

// Only called by the writer thread.
write(input)
    THREAD_LOCAL_ARRAY array
    THREAD_LOCAL_POINTER write_pointer := shared_pointer
    if write_pointer == location_of_last_element(array)
        write_pointer := location_of_first_element(array)
    else
        write_pointer := location_of_next_element(array, write_pointer)
    write_data_at(write_pointer, input)
    shared_pointer := write_pointer
```

Let's call `MAX_READING_DURATION` the maximum period of time that a call to `read()` can take to complete, and `MIN_WRITING_DURATION` the minimum period of time that a call to `write()` can take to complete.

Now, with `shared_pointer` guaranteed to be atomic, as long as `MAX_READING_DURATION < ELEMENT_COUNT(ARRAY) * MIN_WRITING_DURATION`, this scheme should be perfectly safe.

Or have I overlooked something? If not, I'm sure this is a well known thing, and I'd like to know the *proper terminology* is, so I can use that when I explain/advocate this approach to others.

Answer (score 1):

Sufficient memory and the total number of writing threads are not *the* criteria for determining what can and can't be lockless.

One important feature of lock-free programming is that if you suspend a single thread it will never prevent other threads from making progress through their own lock-free operations.

But, more importantly: The main feature your (single-writer) code needs to adhere to in order to be lock-free is 'sequential consistency':

Sequential Consistency means 'all threads agree on the order in which memory operations occurred, and that order is consistent with the order of operations in the program source code'.

If the code can't guarantee Sequential Consistency it must prevent memory reordering. ( Here is more info on Memory Reordering: http://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/ )

Finally, I'd recommend checking out these resources to dig deeper into lock-free multi-threaded programming concepts:
http://concurrencykit.org/presentations/lockfree_introduction/#/
http://www.drdobbs.com/lock-free-data-structures/184401865

Good luck!